# C# How to let processes with different speeds work together

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

In the bellow test scenario i like to trigger some task by using multiple timers. Some event can trigger another event.

An event must finish the process, before a new process can be started. Events that gets triggered, while another event is processing, shall queue up and start once nothing is processing. The timer doesn't need to be accurate.

Once a line has executed the code, which takes just few seconds, the line cant take any new orders for minutes. Thats the purpose im using timers.

The current problem on the code bellow, is that things are getting mixed up in the real App. Line2 starts processing, while Line still hasn't finished. How to make the orders queue up properly and process it?

In the real App `MyTask` will start to run the first lines of code back and forth, after a while the last lines of the `MyTask` code will be executed.

Im a beginner, so please be patient.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        readonly System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        readonly System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

        int leadTime1 = 100;
        int leadTime2 = 100;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TaskStarter();

        }

        private void TaskStarter()
        {
            myTimer1.Tick += new EventHandler(myEventTimer1);
            myTimer2.Tick += new EventHandler(myEventTimer2);

            myTimer1.Interval = leadTime1;
            myTimer2.Interval = leadTime2;

            myTimer1.Start();
        }

        private void myEventTimer1(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            myTimer1.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Line1 Processing ");
            MyTask();
            Console.Write(" Line1 Completed");
            leadTime1.Interval = 5000; // this leadtime is variable and will show how long the line cant be used again, after the code is executed
            myTimer2.Start();
            myTimer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void myEventTimer2(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            myTimer2.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Line2 Processing ");
            MyTask();
            Console.Write(" Line2 Completed");
            leadTime2.Interval = 5000; // this leadtime is variable
            myTimer2.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void MyTask()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int timeExecuteCode = rnd.Next(1000, 5000); // This leadtime does reflect the execution of the real code
            Thread.Sleep(timeExecuteCode );
        }
    }
```

**Update**
Thanks to the input i was able to sort the problems, which made me remove all the timers as they were causing the asynchronous task processing. I not just lock the Lines to a `while loop` till all orders are completed. All is done in a single `Thread`. I think for the most Pro my code will look very ugly. This solution is understandable with my 4 weeks C# experience :)

The 2 List i use and the properties

```
    public class Orders
    {
        public string OrderID { get ; set ; }
        public Orders(string orderID) { OrderID = orderID; }
    }

    public class LineData
    {
        string lineID;
        public string LineID { get { return lineID; } set { lineID = value; } }
        private string orderId;
        public string OrderID { get { return orderId; } set { orderId = value; } }
        public string ID { get { return lineID + OrderID; } private set {; } } 
        public double TaskTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Creating the Line data with the lead times per Line and Part
Adding some sample orders
while loop till all orders are completed

```
    public class Production
    {
        readonly static List<LineData> listLineData = new List<LineData>();
        readonly static List<Orders> listOrders = new List<Orders>();

        static void Main()
        {
            // List Line Processing Master Data 
            listLineData.Add(new LineData { LineID = "Line1", OrderID = "SubPart1", TaskTime = 3 });
            listLineData.Add(new LineData { LineID = "Line1", OrderID = "SubPart2", TaskTime = 3 });
            listLineData.Add(new LineData { LineID = "Line2", OrderID = "Part1", TaskTime = 1 });
            listLineData.Add(new LineData { LineID = "Line3", OrderID = "Part1", TaskTime = 1 });
            listLineData.Add(new LineData { LineID = "Line3", OrderID = "Part2", TaskTime = 2 });

            // Create Order Book 
            listOrders.Add(new Orders("SubPart1"));
            listOrders.Add(new Orders("SubPart2"));
            listOrders.Add(new Orders("Part1"));
            listOrders.Add(new Orders("Part2"));
            listOrders.Add(new Orders("SubPart1"));
            listOrders.Add(new Orders("SubPart2"));
            listOrders.Add(new Orders("Part1"));
            listOrders.Add(new Orders("Part2"));
            listOrders.Add(new Orders("SubPart1"));
            listOrders.Add(new Orders("SubPart2"));
            listOrders.Add(new Orders("Part1"));
            listOrders.Add(new Orders("Part2"));

            while (listOrders.Count > 0)
            {
                CheckProductionLines();
                Thread.Sleep(100)
            }
        }
```

Picking orders from the `listOrder` and assign them to the correct Line.
Using `DateTime.Now` and add the `taskTime` to determine whether a line is busy or not
Sending the orders to `void InitializeProduction(int indexOrder, string line)` to process the order.
In a later step im going to make a function for Line1-Linex, as it is repetitive.

```
        static DateTime timeLine1Busy = new DateTime();
        static DateTime timeLine2Busy = new DateTime();
        static DateTime timeLine3Busy = new DateTime();

        static void CheckProductionLines()
        {            
            // Line 1
            int indexOrderLine1 = listOrders.FindIndex(x => x.OrderID == "SubPart1" || x.OrderID == "SubPart2");
            if (indexOrderLine1 >= 0 && timeLine1Busy < DateTime.Now)
            {
                string id = "Line1" + listOrders[indexOrderLine1].OrderID.ToString();// Construct LineID (Line + Part) for Task
                int indexTasktime = listLineData.FindIndex(x => x.ID == id);    // Get Index LineData where the tasktime is stored
                double taskTime = (listLineData[indexTasktime].TaskTime);       // Get the Task Time for the current order (min.)
                InitializeProduction(indexOrderLine1, "Line1");                 // Push the start button to run the task
                timeLine1Busy = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(taskTime);              // Set the Line to busy 
            }

            // Line2
            int indexOrderLine2 = listOrders.FindIndex(x => x.OrderID == "Part1"); // Pick order Line2
            if (indexOrderLine2 >= 0 && timeLine2Busy < DateTime.Now)
            {
                string id = "Line2" + listOrders[indexOrderLine2].OrderID.ToString();  // Line2 + Order is unique ID in listLineData List
                int indexTasktime = listLineData.FindIndex(x => x.ID == id);// Get Index LineData where the tasktime is stored
                double taskTime = (listLineData[indexTasktime].TaskTime);      // Get the Task Time for the current order (min.)
                InitializeProduction(indexOrderLine2, "Line2");             // Push the start button to run the task
                timeLine2Busy = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(taskTime);              // Set the Line to busy 
            }

            // Line 3
            int indexOrderLine3 = listOrders.FindIndex(x => x.OrderID == "Part1" || x.OrderID == "Part2"); // Pick order
            if (indexOrderLine3 >= 0 && timeLine3Busy < DateTime.Now)
            {
                string id = "Line3" + listOrders[indexOrderLine3].OrderID.ToString();  // Line3 + Order is unique ID in listLineData List
                int indexTasktime = listLineData.FindIndex(x => x.ID == id);// Get Index LineData where the tasktime is stored
                double taskTime = (listLineData[indexTasktime].TaskTime);      // Get the Task Time for the current order (min.)
                InitializeProduction(indexOrderLine3, "Line3");             // Push the start button to run the task
                timeLine3Busy = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(taskTime);              // Set the Line to busy 
            }
        }
```

Here i `InitializeProduction` the production
Remove the order from `listOrders`
in real here will be processed many tasks

```
        static void InitializeProduction(int indexOrder, string line)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);                                             //simulates the inizialsation code
            Debug.WriteLine($"{line} {listOrders[indexOrder].OrderID} Completed "); 
            listOrders.RemoveAt(indexOrder);                                //Remove Order from List
        }

    }
```

Im sure you will see a lot of space for improvement. If simple things can or even must be applied, im listening :)

Comment: Your approach inherently suggests that you want the processes to be conducted in parallel, or "asynchronously". May I ask why you have chosen timers since you want the processes completed in order? Also, I think you may have a typo in your example code; you attach the `EventHandler` to `myTimer1` twice?

Comment: EventHandler to myTimer1, just a copy paste error. Its fixed :) I have a task list witch holds several orders. The myEventTimers will pick an order an execute them. The picked order has a leadtime, which will set the timer accordingly. While Line1 and Line2 could have different leadtimes for the same order. I use the timer function  because i dont want the thread beeing locked to a line, while another line could process a order.

Comment: i have added the leadTime change to the code. It represents how long the line cant be reused again. Note: while the the code which starts the line will execute quickly, the line will be busy for minutes to get an new order.

Comment: If I understand, you have `myOrders = List<Order>`, where an `Order` has some work to be processed with an associated `Leadtime`. You have a number of `Line`, which will process an `Order`, and subsequently be "busy" for the `Leadtime`? Like a model of a production facility?

Comment: Yes, its about this... Just that the lead time is associated to the machine and order type. orderX can take 15min on Line1, but 10min on Line 2. Some orders can be done just on Line2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Addition after comments at the end**

Your problem screams for a producer-consumer pattern. This lesser known pattern has a producer who produces things that a consumer consumes.

The speed in which the producer produces items can be different than the speed in which the consumer can consume. Sometimes the producer produces faster, sometimes the producer produces slower.

In your case, the producer produces "requests to execute a task". The consumer will execute a task one at a time.

For this I use Nuget package: [Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow](http://Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow). It can do a lot more, but in your case, usage is simple.

Normally there are a lot of multi-threading issues you have to think about, like critical sections in the send-receive buffer. TPL will handle them for your.

If the Producer is started, it produces requests to do something, to execute and await an `Action<Task>`. The producer will these requests in a `BufferBlock<Action<Task>>`. It will produce as fast a possible.

First a factory, that will create `Action<Task>` with random execution time. Note that every created action is not executed yet, thus the task is not running!

```
class ActionFactory
{
    private readonly Random rnd = new Random();

    public Action<Task> Create()
    {
        TimeSpan timeExecuteCode = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(rnd.Next(1000, 5000));
        return _ => Task.Delay(timeExecuteCode);
        // if you want, you can use Thread.Sleep
    }
}
```

The producer is fairly simple:

```
class Producer
{
    private readonly BufferBlock<Action<Task>> buffer = new BufferBlock<Action<Task>>();

    public TaskFactory TaskFactory {get; set;}

    public ISourceBlock<Action<Task> ProducedActions => buffer;

    public async Task ProduceAsync()
    {
        // Create several tasks and put them on the buffer
        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        {
            Action<Task> createdAction = this.TaskFactory.Create();
            await this.buffer.SendAsync(createdAction);
        }

        // notice listeners to my output that I won't produce anything anymore
        this.buffer.Complete();
    }
```

If you want, you can optimize this: while SendAsync, you could create the next action. then await SendAsync task, before sending the next action. For simplicity I didn't do this.

The Consumer needs an input, that accepts `Action<Task>` objects. It will read this input, execute the action and wait until the action is completed before fetching the next input from the buffer.

```
class Consumer
{
    public ISourceBlock<Action<Task>> ActionsToConsume {get; set;}

    public async Task ConsumeAsync()
    {
         // wait until the producer has produced something,
         // or says that nothing will be produced anymore
         while (await this.ActionsToConsume.OutputAvailableAsync())
         {
              // the Producer has produced something; fetch it
              Action<Task> actionToExecute = this.ActionsToConsume.ReceiveAsync();

              // execute the action, and await the eturned Task
              await actionToExecute();

              // wait until Producer produces a new action.
         }

         // if here: producer notifies completion: nothing is expected anymore
    }
```

Put it all together:

```
TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory();
Producer producer = new Producer
{
    TaskFactory = factory;
}
Consumer consumer = new Consumer
{
    Buffer = producer.ProducedActions;
}

// Start Producing and Consuming and wait until everything is ready
var taskProduce = producer.ProduceAsync();
var taskConsume = consumer.ConsumeAsync();

// now producer is happily producing actions and sending them to the consumer.
// the consumer is waiting for actions to consume
// await until both tasks are finished:
await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] {taskProduce, taskConsume});
```

### Addition after comment: do it with less code

The above seems a lot of work. I created separate classes, so you could see who is responsible for what. If you want, you can do it all with one buffer and two methods: a method that produces and a method that consumes:

```
private readonly BufferBlock<Action<Task>> buffer = new BufferBlock<Action<Task>>();

public async Task ProduceTasksAsync()
{
    // Create several tasks and put them on the buffer
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        Action<Task> createdAction = ...
        await this.buffer.SendAsync(createdAction);
    }

    // producer will not produce anything anymore:
    buffer.Complete();
}

async Task ConsumeAsync()
{
    while (await this.ActionsToConsume.OutputAvailableAsync())
    {
        // the Producer has produced something; fetch it, execute it
        Action<Task> actionToExecute = this.ActionsToConsume.ReceiveAsync();
        await actionToExecute();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
async Task ProduceAndConsumeAsync()
{
    var taskProduce = producer.ProduceAsync();
    var taskConsume = consumer.ConsumeAsync();
    await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] {taskProduce, taskConsume});

}
```

Comment: Yes, its screams exactly for that :) The producer is in some cases quicker as the consumer and vise versa. But this code is fairly to complected for a dump beginner like me :))) it will take some time to understand everything, what you have done with this code. From your description, the code is doing what i need. I tought my problem could be solved on a much easier manner. Many thanks for your great input, it will keep me busy for some time. :)

Comment: I would like to tick your solution as the right one, as I think it's a great approach. I would also like to update the title, so people can find your code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that both timers run on the same UI event loop. that means that while `timer1` is doing it's event no other events are executed on that thread. The solution to this is to use tha `async` `await` pattern that runs code in the background in your case you can do something like this:

```
private async void myEventTimer1(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    myTimer1.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Line1 Processing ");
    await MyTask();
    Console.Write(" Line1 Completed");
    myTimer1.Interval = 5000; // this leadtime is variable
    myTimer2.Start();
    myTimer1.Enabled = true;
}

private async void myEventTimer2(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    myTimer2.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Line2 Processing ");
    await MyTask();
    Console.Write(" Line2 Completed");
    myTimer2.Interval = 5000; // this leadtime is variable
    myTimer2.Enabled = true;
}

private async Task MyTask()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int tleadtime = rnd.Next(1000, 5000);
    await Task.Delay(tleadtime);
}
```

This runs `MyTask` (really just the `Delay` part) in the background, but continues in the foreground once it is complete.

Comment: I'm quite confident that `Timer.Tick` is dispatched on it's own thread, not the UI thread. However you're right that this will allow the thread to return for the completion on the `myEventTimerX` events.

Comment: The change is not working, i need just one line executing the code a the time. the result should be `Line1 Processing Line1 Completed`

Comment: I edited the answer I think you need to change `myTimer1.Interval` every time and not just `leadTime`

Comment: it is miss leading... actually the `tleadTime` is just representing the time that the real code has to run. while `leadTime1` is the time the line cant be used anymore, once a task has been initialized. will edit this in the code. yes, it has to be myTimer1 = leadTime1 in the real scenario.

Comment: i get also after the edit following result in the console `Line1 Completed Line2 CompletedLine1 Processing` Its a key requirement, that line1 will complete, before line2 starts processing.

Comment: aha. i see. then dont use my code. do it how you did it before and only change `leadTime` to `myTimer1.Interval`

Comment: That was not the issue, my problem is that in the real code, the `MyTask` does not execute from the beginning to the end.  It starts and keeps repeating the first lines of code,  after a while it starts to repeat the end of the lines. It looks like the timer event are messing the sequenz of `MyTask` In the real app I'm using 10 timers,.

Comment: It's not repeating the first line of code @RobertoPagnotta, what you are seeing, presumably during debug stepping, is multiple threads starting the same block of code. When you "step" you are not necessarily following the same thread. Use `Ctrl+Alt+H` to open the threads window. You'll see that when your code sequence is seemingly jumping around, you are view the positon of different threads.

Comment: That's what I like to explain, the total lines of code are correct, just the sequence is wrong. It takes from `Line 1` and `Line2` the input, which will execute first the beginning of `MyTask` and at the end the last lines of code. Thanks for the hint, to check the thread processing by `Ctrl+Alt+H`, this helps a lot to identified such problems.

Answer (score 1):

Now to be clear, this isn't technically an answer to your question as you have asked it, but I believe it will produce the underlying behavior that you asking for (in comments), and I believe in helping people.

We have three classes, `Order`, `Line` and `Factory` written in Console Application as an example.

`Order` is straight forward, it has two properties, an identifying name, and a leadtime in seconds.

```
public class Order
{
    public string OrderName { get; set; }
    public int LeadTimeSeconds { get; set; }

    public Order(string orderName, int leadTimeSeconds)
    {
        OrderName = orderName;
        LeadTimeSeconds = leadTimeSeconds;
    }
}
```

`Line` inherits from a `BackgroundWorker` [MSDN - BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker). I won't go into detail here as there are many posts on the subject, but you may delegate to the `DoWork` event that is invoked asynchronously. They allow you to do something continuously (or prolonged periods) without blocking behaviors since they expose a `CancelAsync()` method. `Line` also has reference to your `Queue<Order>`. A `Queue<T>` is a nice collection as it allows you to easily `Dequeue()` the next item in line. Within the constructor, `Line` calls `RunWorkerAsync()`, invoking the `DoWork` event, and in turn the handler `Line_ProcessOrder`.

```
public class Line: BackgroundWorker
{
    public string LineName { get; set; }
    public Queue<Order> OrderQueue { get; set; }

    public Line (string lineName, Queue<Order> orderQueue)
    {
        LineName = lineName;
        OrderQueue = orderQueue;
        DoWork += Line_ProcessOrder;
        RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void Line_ProcessOrder(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Order targetOrder;
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        while (true)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (OrderQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    targetOrder = OrderQueue.Dequeue();
                    Console.WriteLine($"{LineName} is processing {targetOrder.OrderName}");
                    Thread.Sleep(targetOrder.LeadTimeSeconds * 1000);
                    Console.WriteLine($"{LineName} finished {targetOrder.OrderName}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, `Factory` brings this all together. We can have any number of `Lines`, sharing a `Queue<Order>`, created from any `IEnumerable<Queue>` that you may of otherwise had. Note that the `Lines` start working immediately on their construction. You may wish to add `Start()` and `Stop()` methods for example.

```
public class Factory
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Order> Orders = new List<Order>()
        {
            new Order("Order1",10),
            new Order("Order2",8),
            new Order("Order3",5),
            new Order("Order4",15)
        };

        Queue<Order> OrderQueue = new Queue<Order>(Orders);

        Line Line1 = new Line("Line1", OrderQueue);
        Line Line2 = new Line("Line2", OrderQueue);

        while (true) { }
    }
}
```

This may not be exactly what you needed, but I hope it can take you away from the timer approach towards asynchronous programming.

Comment: This will take me some Time to understand. Need to try and error and read me thru the new stuff. What i got from your explanation, is that a list gets created where the orders will be released accordingly. But does it also work if the `Lines` cant process the same item? Just from understanding, it could happen that a item which cant be processed just by Line1, will block Line2? I think this are things that i have to test by myself. I think i need 2 `List<Order> Orders` and add it as selection in the `if (OrderQueue.Count > 0)` statement, so that always a order for `Line1` and `Line2` is avail.

Comment: This concept that a `Line` can or cannot process an `Item`/`Order` is moving away from what you originally asked. In my implantation, you could add properties to the `Order` class, and to the `Line` class to determine in some conditional logic if the `Line` can process the `Order`.  Currently a `Line` will just take the next `Order` in the `Queue` and process it, so long as there is an `Order` available. That's what the `(OrderQueue.Count > 0)` is: Are there `Order`s pending?

Comment: Try to move forward and post a new specific question if something doesn't work. You won't be provided with a full solution, as much as I and @HaraldCoppoolse have tired :)

Comment: Jap, thats exactly my approach, i dont expect a final solution served on the table :) Im absolutely willing to understand the code in details, which im going to paste in my application. Im curerntly going thru MSDN - BackgroundWorker and Queue<>, this is new to me and sound promising to solve my problem. Thansk for your asome support :)

Comment: You're very welcome. The other answer looks promising also. Don't forget to upvote those answers that helped you ;)